# How can I use SnapToDevicePixels and StrokeDashArray

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L 12 0 L 12 12 L 0 12 Z M 6 0 L 6 12 M 0 6 L 12 6" StrokeDashArray="1 1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels='True">
</Path>
```

However it looks horribly fuzzy on my screen.
Is there a solution?

Comment: Don't think so, there is a trick for Text
 
<TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="5" T TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"> 
This is a Test. Display text is crisp at small sizes. 
</TextBlock>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a crisp, dashed path and you may be able to get the results you want by declaring the RenderOptions.EdgeMode as Aliased to prevent the framework from interpolating the path outline when a dash falls between pixel boundaries:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L 12 0 L 12 12 L 0 12 Z M 6 0 L 6 12 M 0 6 L 12 6" StrokeDashArray="1 1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
</Path>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. The `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` did the trick! I've been searching for this for a very long time. Thanks for answering!!